# OutOfMemoryError occured : Java heap space in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, out-of-memory

I am creating play-based web application with java. When I run it an error occured with the following error:

```
Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Application.java around line 12)
OutOfMemoryError occured : Java heap space

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Java heap space
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:227)
at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:585)
at java.io.StringWriter.toString(StringWriter.java:193)
at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:248)
at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
at play.mvc.results.RenderTemplate.<init>(RenderTemplate.java:24)
at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:657)
at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:637)
at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:692)
at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:12)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:540)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:498)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:474)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:469)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:157)
... 1 more
```

Anybody know or maybe has the same problem, please give me advise.

Comment: You can run your app with more memory using: `play run your_app -Xss1m`

Comment: you should profile your application for [Memory Leaks](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/) - if there is no leak you can increase your memory amount

Comment: Thanks Jonas and olihoiz for your answers, it might can help me solving the problem.

Comment: If one of the answers you got solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

A quick workaround would be to increase the memory of the JVM (how that's done depends on the JVM in use, Oracle's JVM would support the `-Xmx...m` option, where ... represents the maximum memory in megabytes).

The JVM might initially get too little memory, if that's not the case then checking the memory usage should help, e.g. using jmap (create heap dumps) and jhat (analyze heap dumps).

Answer (score 1):

At the google-list there was a few month ago someone who pointed out that with some constructs the groovy-template engine needs a lot of memory. I assume you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me occasionally too.  @Thomas's answer is a better solution, but if you need a quick fix just shut down and restart Play.