# Play Framework 1.2.5 : OutOfMemoryError occured : Java heap space in play framework

Tags: java, out-of-memory, playframework-1.x

I gett `OutOfMemoryError` while querying MongoDb with the 400k records.
I have a User collection with around 400k records. When I try to retrieve all the users (to dump it in elastic search), I get the  `OutOfMemoryError` error.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331798/outofmemoryerror-occured-java-heap-space-in-play-framework) link and added *jvm.memory=-Xms64m -Xmx1024m* in the application.config, but still the same exception.

Here is my stack trace -

```
OutOfMemoryError occured : Java heap space

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Java heap space
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:237)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:209)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:181)
        at org.bson.BasicBSONObject.<init>(BasicBSONObject.java:45)
        at com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.<init>(BasicDBObject.java:42)
        at com.mongodb.DefaultDBCallback._create(DefaultDBCallback.java:124)
        at com.mongodb.DefaultDBCallback.create(DefaultDBCallback.java:87)
        at org.bson.BasicBSONCallback.objectStart(BasicBSONCallback.java:68)
        at com.mongodb.DefaultDBCallback.objectStart(DefaultDBCallback.java:63)
        at org.bson.BasicBSONCallback.objectStart(BasicBSONCallback.java:63)
        at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:206)
        at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:197)
        at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:207)
        at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:80)
        at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:58)
        at com.mongodb.DefaultDBDecoder.decode(DefaultDBDecoder.java:56)
        at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:66)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:128)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:79)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:218)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:189)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result._advance(DBApiLayer.java:452)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result.hasNext(DBApiLayer.java:418)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:503)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:523)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1520)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1332)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1318)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:504)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:499)
        at com.salambc.service.ProfileService.getUsers(ProfileService.java:895)
        at controllers.Admin.index(Admin.java:56)
```

Comment: How much memory can you give it? I would try the most it can take first and see if that makes a difference and then work out if it can be reduced.

Comment: Note that an out of memory error is often not caused by the piece of code where it happens; it is only the place where the JVM runs out of memory, it can easily be caused by something else. A profiler may give some more insight into where all the memory is going.

Comment: I can give max 2 GB memory (As I am trying it locally and my RAM is around 3GB)..

Comment: As I already given around 1GB memory. Does it not sufficient for 4 Lakh records and other manipulations ???

Comment: Try reducing it to 100,000 records. If that helps, then we can be sure that it can be solved by throwing more RAM. Then you should look at reducing the memory footprint.

Comment: We don't know the size of each "record", and we do not know what is it that you are trying to do with it, so it is impossible to comment much   about how you can reduce memory usage. But try reducing the number of records if this problem goes away, so that we know where the problem is.

Comment: Yes @Raze2dust, its worked perfectly fine with 100,000 records. So ultimately I need to extend JVM memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run out of memory because you load too much objects into memory.

Loading so much objects in a java memory isn't a good practice. You can't scale if a lot of users try to execute this use case.

Allowing more memory to your java process can solve your current bug but isn't a solution in the long term.

Try to think of another design where you can do some computation in your persistent store or load you data by small chuncks of data (100 or 1000) because loading chunk of data lead to predictible memory consumpltion

Answer (score 4):

Please check you application, you run out of memory because you have many big objects in memory. I met the same problem with that... Because all variable/function in Play! is **static**, so some of them cannot be released by GC.

Please check the way you use TemplateLoader, RenderArgs, Jobs... And try to reduce play pool and job pool (if you was setting on), best is 14 play pool for 4GB RAM (in my case).